# Wpforms dropdown menu populate with SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms, plugins

I am creating form in Wpforms. I am adding code to make dropdown menu populated with data from database.

I have code next:

```
function wpforms_sql_list(){

   $hostname = "localhost";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";
   $dbName = "DB name";


   $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName);

   $query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB name'";

   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   $sqlitem = array();
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push( $sqlitem, $row1);
        }

    foreach($sqlitem as $raw1){
    return apply_filters( 'wpforms_sql_list', $raw1);
    }
}
```

Now I have problems because if I run in wordpress I get only dubled first database table in dropdown menu.

If I make:

```
    return apply_filters( 'wpforms_sql_list', $sqlitem);
```

I get correct number of table but instead of names is written array.
[Picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwvY6.png)

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow the wordpress structure to retrieve data from wordpress database like below way :

1) wordpress table see(https://prnt.sc/q71e1q)

2) Fetch data from wordpress table

```
 global $wpdb;
     $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `table_name`"); 
       echo "<select>";
          foreach($data as $damenu){
            echo "<option>".$damenu->name."</option>";
       } 
echo "</select>";
```

3) **Output** :

[image]